# Excel Countifs Function where one of the criteria is a list of names

Tags: excel

I am trying to use a countifs formula to count the number of transactions in a zip code that were performed by any agent within a list of ~100 agents. My formula is currently =COUNTIFS(BuyAgent!A:A,ChaseAgentCoverage!C:C,BuyAgent!B:B,ZipStats!A2)

BuyAgent!A:A is the name of the agent in the transaction
ChaseAgentCoverage!C:C is the name of the Agents we want as the criteria (around 100 agents)
BuyAgent!B:B is the zipcode for the transactions
ZipStats!A2 is the criteria zip cell

I am getting the incorrect numbers and am unsure on how to go about this as the agent criteria is a list of names.

Comment: Wrap it in a SUMPRODUCT, but change:`ChaseAgentCoverage!C:C` to the actual datset `ChaseAgentCoverage!C2:C100` or the formula will slow the calcs to a crawl and will error if used too many times.

Comment: Ok thank you, that worked. I did try to use SUMPRODUCT but didn't change the range and it was freezing my excel